# Gmail "On Behalf Of" Feature in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I use Gmail with Mail.app. As you know Gmail allows replying mails as someone else (by changing `From` header of the sent e-mail). If you don't know, you can register multiple mails to Gmail (your personal mail, work mail etc.) and you can send mail from them from one account.

Let's say you have 3 mails registered in GMail: `g@gmail.com`, `a@a.a` and `b@b.b`. Your account is `g@gmail.com` in this case. When you use GMail web interface, if you receive a mail redirected from `a@a.a`, when you press Reply, it sends your mail as `a@a.a` (or you can choose other accounts to mimic one of your e-mail addresses as sender).

However when I'm in Mail.app, I'm only able to send mail as `g@gmail.com`, any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under `Accounts` in `Preferences`, there's a field there called "Email Address:".  You can put a comma-separated list of addresses in there, like this:

[image: Multiple Emails]

Now your "Compose" window will have a "From" popup menu that lets you choose your sending address:

[image: Choose your from address]

AFAIK, this works for pretty much any mail account type, as long as your mail provider allows you to muck around with the `From:` header.

Comment: solution suggested only works for mobile me accounts....

Comment: No, I'm able to use them with my google apps account and POP3 account I have from school (which is also registered on Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Accounts' in 'Preferences' change the 'Email Address:' to the address you want to use. I don't believe you can switch addresses at send time. You'll have to add a separate account for each email address you want to send from.

Comment: That's so sad :(